# Kafka MongoDB Sink only one record from table

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb, mongodb-kafka-connector

I am using ksqlDB, Where I have created a table from the stream. when I fire select query in that table it gives me all the record properly. Now I want to sink that table in MongoDB. I am also able to create a sink between the Kafka table to MongoDB. But somehow it sinks only one record into it(MongoDB). Whereas in the table I have 100 records. Below is my MongoDB sink connector.

```
{
  "name": "MongoSinkConnectorConnector_1",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "topics": "FEEDS",
    "connection.uri": "mongodb://xxx:xxx@x.x.x.x:27017/",
    "database": "xxx",
    "max.num.retries": "1000000",
    "writemodel.strategy": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.UpdateOneTimestampsStrategy",
    "value.projection.type": "allowlist",
    "value.projection.list": "id",
    "document.id.strategy": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.PartialValueStrategy",
    "buffer.capacity": "20000",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://x.x.x.x:8081",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "insert.mode": "upsert"
  }
}
```

I could not able to understand that, what's the reason behind that. Any help appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can set the "batch.size" property in the Sink Connector property and also you can have a better write model strategy that you can read through Mongo DB Source Connector Official documentation https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/connectors/cc-mongo-db-source.html.

Comment: thanks for the reply but it is for the cloud solution. Not for local setup. And the surprising part is I have another connecter as well for the different topic and it's sink well.

Comment: Sorry. What do you meant by cloud? Can elaborate, how your number of records something to do with cloud.

Comment: I mean that what you suggest for MongoDB Atlas, not for the MongoDB local setup